# Django _set.all() filter in QuerySet

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-queryset

I have database and I want to extract specific data of specific user from queryset. Now i have this

**VIEW**

```
def index(request):
    customerByName = Customer.objects.get(name='pablo')
    shopListById = ShopList.objects.get(transaction_id=1)
    shpoListSpecific = customerByName.shoplist_set.all()
    specificProducts = shopListById.shoplistproduct_set.all()

    context = {'customerByName':customerByName, 'shpoListSpecific':shpoListSpecific, 'shopListById':shopListById,
     'specificProducts': specificProducts}
    return render(request, 'QuickShopperApp/home.html', context)
```

**MODELS**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    device = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name:
            name = self.name
        else:
            name = self.device
        return str(name)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ShopList(models.Model): # cart
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    #product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class ShopListProduct(models.Model): # each ShopList will have multiple ShopListProduct
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    shopList = models.ForeignKey(ShopList, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) #shoplistitem.shoplist
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

**template.html**

```
<h3>specificProducts: {{specificProducts}}</h3>
```

On my side i see items of specific customer.

**specificProducts: <QuerySet [<ShopListProduct: Apple>, <ShopListProduct: Cucumber>, <ShopListProduct: Cucumber>]>**

How can i get only Apple, Cucumber, Cucumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
'specificProducts': specificProducts.values_list('product__name')

or

'specificProducts': list(specificProducts.values_list('product__name', flat=True))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: thanks for answer Mate, now i have this: 
<QuerySet [('Apple',), ('Cucumber',), ('Cucumber',)]>

if i do forloop i have this:
('Apple',)
('Cucumber',)
('Cucumber',)

i want only raw value like : 
Apple
Cucumber
Cucumber